# JTextField or JFormattedTextField for digits, comma and dots?

Tags: java, swing, filter, jtextfield, restriction

I need to restrict a text field input to just digits, comma and dots. 
I could do this using a `DocumentFilter` and a `JTextField` but what if I wanted to use a `JFormattedTextField`?

I've tried to look at some examples but I didn't understand.

Comment: Have you read this Oracle tutorial as part of your examples? [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: Yes, but it works only for digits. Doesn't work with commas and dots.

Comment: There are a lot of examples on there to go off of. You can then simply call [MaskFormatter#setValidCharacters(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html#setValidCharacters-java.lang.String-). This is by far the easiest way to accomplish what you want. I posted that link because I assumed there would be a mention of this, but I guess not.

Comment: Ok, now it works but how can I avoid to set a mask? I just want to set the valid characters. I've tried this `MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter(); formatter.setValidCharacters("0123456789,.");` but doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a strict character limit you can use?

Comment: I could but I'd rather not.

Comment: `I just want to set the valid characters.` - why? `now it works but how can I avoid to set a mask?` - so you have your answer, why are you trying to make using the formatted text field so complicated? What is the problem with using the mask that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @camickr by setting a mask the textfield doesn't work properly. It's like split the text field into cells and doesn't allow me to put text unless I click every time on a different cell.